# How to see com.fasterxml.jackson log messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, jackson

I am trying to debug an issue with Jackson and I would like to see log entries from `com.fasterxml.jackson`. Unfortunately this solution [How to see org.codehaus.jackson log messages - using logging.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675002/how-to-see-org-codehaus-jackson-log-messages-using-logging-properties) doesn't do anything for me because Spring Boot 2 uses the updated `com.fasterxml.jackson` package, and I'm using logback for my log config. I am using Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE which uses Jackson 2.9.

I have the following in `logback-spring.xml`

```
<logger name="com.fasterxml.jackson" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</logger>
```

(I have tried with additivity set to true as well)

and the following in `application.properties`

```
logging.level.com.fasterxml.jackson=TRACE
```

but nothing is showing up in my logs for Jackson.

Comment: Worth checking does it really logs ? Just checked ObjectMapper. It does not have any logger.

Comment: @bittu Hmmm I hadn't considered that. That would be unfortunate.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326976/spring-rest-using-jackson-400-bad-request-logging#answer-53770263

Comment: @WesternGun Thank you for taking the time to do that :)

Comment: [Here is a solution for Quarkus users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65206075/812102).